# ArcGIS API for Python geometric filter of feature layer producing Runtime Error: 'geometry parameter invalid'

Tags: filter, feature-layer, arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to select a handful of features from an Enterprise Portal feature layer using the ArcGIS API for Python. Specifically I am trying to do a spatial selection, where the selected features are within a certain bounding box.

My code is based on the code snippets in the API reference documentation pages for the [arcgis.features FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featurelayer) query() function, the [arcgis.geometry.filters module](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.filters.html#envelope-intersects), and the [arcgis.geometry Geometry and Polygon sections](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html#polygon). Code is as follows (with exact names simplified for privacy reasons):

```
# Import Statements
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geometry import Geometry
from arcgis.geometry.filters import *
import arcpy

# Instantiate Connection to Portal
gis = GIS("portal_url", username="my_username")

# Get item from portal and set spatial reference
portalItem = gis.content.get('itemID')
portalLayer = portalItem.layers[0]
spatialReference = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

# Create a filter feature Geometry object
AOI = Geometry({
  "rings" : [[-108.46, 35.12],[-108.48, 35.12],[-108.48, 35.18],[-108.46, 35.18],
              [-108.46, 35.12]],
  "spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326} })

# construct a geometry filter using the filter geometry
AOI_geom_filter = intersects(AOI, spatialReference)

# query a feature layer for features that meet filter criteria
subset = portallLayer.query(geometry_filter=AOI_geom_filter, outfields='OBJECTID, LAT, LON')
```

This results in an error:

```
Unable to complete operation.
'geometry' parameter is invalid.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-bb0dabd89dd0> in <module>
      9 
     10 # query a feature layer for features that meet filter criteria
---> 11 NMparcels = parcelLayer.query(geometry_filter=AOI_geom_filter, outfields='OBJECTID, LAT, LON')

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\layer.py in query(self, where, out_fields, time_filter, geometry_filter, return_geometry, return_count_only, return_ids_only, return_distinct_values, return_extent_only, group_by_fields_for_statistics, statistic_filter, result_offset, result_record_count, object_ids, distance, units, max_allowable_offset, out_sr, geometry_precision, gdb_version, order_by_fields, out_statistics, return_z, return_m, multipatch_option, quantization_parameters, return_centroid, return_all_records, result_type, historic_moment, sql_format, return_true_curves, return_exceeded_limit_features, as_df, **kwargs)
    698 
    699         params['returnCountOnly'] = True
--> 700         record_count = self._query(url, params, raw=as_raw)
    701         if 'maxRecordCount' in self.properties:
    702             max_records = self.properties['maxRecordCount']

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\layer.py in _query(self, url, params, raw)
   1397         """ returns results of query """
   1398         result = self._con.post(path=url,
-> 1399                                 postdata=params, token=self._token)
   1400         if 'error' in result:
   1401             raise ValueError(result)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\_impl\connection.py in post(self, path, postdata, files, ssl, compress, is_retry, use_ordered_dict, add_token, verify_cert, token, try_json, out_folder, file_name, force_bytes, add_headers)
   1175                                          verify_cert=verify_cert, is_retry=True)
   1176 
-> 1177                 self._handle_json_error(resp_json['error'], errorcode)
   1178                 return None
   1179 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\_impl\connection.py in _handle_json_error(self, error, errorcode)
   1196 
   1197         errormessage = errormessage + "\n(Error Code: " + str(errorcode) +")"
-> 1198         raise RuntimeError(errormessage)
   1199 
   1200 class _StrictURLopener(request.FancyURLopener):

RuntimeError: Unable to complete operation.
'geometry' parameter is invalid.
(Error Code: 400)
```

I've done the following testing to try to figure out why this is erroring (given that I'm following the example in the documentation very closely):

- Checked the geometry of the AOI object (polygon type, correct coordinates), including checking that the coordinates are listed in the correct format and order when creating the AOI object.
- Visualized portalLayer in a map - it appears as it should, and covers the AOI
- Ran a non-geometric query (where='OBJECTID<10') on portalLayer (worked as expected)
- Look at the result of `AOI_geom_filter` - it's a dictionary that seems reasonable, although the documentation pages linked above don't actually say what intersects() should output.

**Can anyone see what's missing and leading to the error?**

I'm working on the ArcGIS Jupyter Notebook environment (ArcGIS 10.7.1) on Windows 10. I did note that running `arcgis.__version__` said I have Version 1.6.1 instead of Version 1.8.2 which is what the documentation webpages are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution a couple days later. In the line where I created the AOI Geometry item I was missing a set of brackets (added below). This meant that the array used to create the geometry was short a dimension. It was still recognizable as a polygon when I checked the type of the geometry, but the geometry filter and query had problems with it. The extra set of brackets makes more sense when one remembers that the Geometry item could have multiple polygons in one item.

```
AOI = Geometry({
  "rings" : [[[-108.46, 35.12],[-108.48, 35.12],[-108.48, 35.18],[-108.46, 35.18],
              [-108.46, 35.12]]],
  "spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326} })
```